# 'Already defined in .obj' error, Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
1>knightTour_Main.obj : error LNK2005: "int p" (?p@@3HA) already defined in Definitions.obj
1>knightTour_Main.obj : error LNK2005: "int q" (?q@@3HA) already defined in Definitions.obj
```

Error^

This is the code where I've defined it in a header file:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int p,q;

int f( int,  int,const int [][8],const int [][8], int [],int []);
```

I've tried

```
extern int p,q;
```

But I get this error after that

```
1>knightTour_Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int p" (?p@@3HA)
1>knightTour_Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int q" (?q@@3HA)
```

Do you recommend anything else? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the `int p,q;` with `extern int p,q;` was correct, but you also need to include `int p,q;` in exactly one .cpp file

If you have a definition (`int p,q;`) in a header, then you'll get one copy of `p` and `q` allocated for each file that includes that header, and they conflict (the "already defined" error). If you replace it with a declaration (`extern int p,q;`), you don't get `p` or `q` allocated anywhere.